# learning Gurobi for MIP calculation

Tags: python, mixed-integer-programming

I am a new learner of Unix, python and Gurobi for MIP calculation. I basically finish reading the quick start guide in Gurobi website but still feel that I need more training to use this combination to automatically write MIP input files. Do anyone have some suggestion on any available trainings (especially in using Unix or Python to automatically generate the input file for Ising model with large grid sizes). Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! This questions is a bit off-topic on this site, since it is about a very specific software (for which dedicated discussion groups exist, such as https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gurobi).